# facing issue with deleting items from cart in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

can we delete two items at a time from the cart in codeigniter?? i try to delete but it is not happened. because the rowid is different for every items in the cart. Anyone Knows the solution of this problem?

Comment: Do you have any common point on the both cart item?

Comment: Can you show the code you've tried?

Comment: No these items are not common they have different ids and different rowid

Comment: I think you should read the docs before posting:  https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/cart.html#updating-the-cart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can delete multiple items at the same time
You can set the qty to zero for multiple items https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/cart.html#updating-the-cart

```
 $data = array(
        array(
                'rowid'   => 'b99ccdf16028f015540f341130b6d8ec',
                'qty'     => 0
        ),
        array(
                'rowid'   => 'xw82g9q3r495893iajdh473990rikw23',
                'qty'     => 0
        )
);

$this->cart->update($data);
```

Comment: But in buy one get one free option what to do? because when i delete one item its deleted but the free item is still there in cart contents then i have to  remove this item again. i want to remove one item with its free item should be remove as well.

Comment: @FarhanYousaf add a check before removing item and check if its BOGO if thats the case then remove both the items

Comment: OK Thanks @shantanu